# A general word for someone performing an academic service?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I'm looking for a general word that could be used for anyone performing an academic service of some kind, including, for instance:

- board members
- external experts
- student representatives
- peer reviewers/referees
- ...

From a strict language point of view, the most obvious word (or rather: phrase) to express 'someone providing a service' would perhaps seem to be "service provider", but I have a feeling that's mainly used for non-academic services – or am I wrong about this?

Comment: "Educational service provider" exists, but it refers to organizations that contract with schools (usually at the k12 level), not individuals. I can't think of a concise expression that would describe what you want.

Comment: @Laurel Hm, as I suspected, then :/ Would "person providing the service" work (for lack of a better solution)? Or would "person performing the service" be better? Or something else entirely?

Comment: Is there a word with this meaning in your native language? What does it translate to in dictionaries and online translation services?

Comment: @gotube Indeed there is, problem is that it translates into any number of words and expressions, depending on context, so that doesn't help much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that there is a single term to describe such varied roles. Those directly working as educators may be termed '*academics*, and other terms such as '*faculty members*' (chiefly US English) mainly refer to those. If some of the positions you listed as examples are normally occupied by persons qualified as educators it is possible the terms may extend to them, but not to support services. In the UK, anyone working in a school in support services may be called an *ancillary worker*.

However, everything academic falls under into **the education sector**, which is defined as:

> All elements of an economy that consists of a variety of education provider, schools, colleges, universities, organizations, agencies, businesses or form of unity assembly, unity council, unity legislature, unity senate, unity house of representatives, unity parliament, unity government, local unity government, regional unity government or national unity government that have the agreement, contract, role, responsibility and purpose of providing a form of education to members of the public.

So, the broadest possible term for anyone working in education including support services may be *education sector workers*.